# How to return JSON object from DataTable of Sql Command in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: datatable, json.net

I want to return a JSON object while getting data from DataTable of Sql Command.

Here is my method:

```
       private static JSON ExecuteDatatableJSON(SqlCommand sqlCommand, int timeoutInSecs = 30)
       {
        DataTable dt = null;
        JSON json = null;

        try
        {
            dt = ExecuteDatatable(sqlCommand);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message + ", Method: " + (new StackFrame().GetMethod().Name), ex);
        }

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt); // this is the line causing issue

        return json;
        }
```

Comment: I do not have a json class.

Comment: yes json is null;

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you trying to return a JSON string literal from [tag:asp.net-core], specifically [tag:asp.net-core-3.1] where `System.Text.Json` is used instead of Newtonsoft?  Or is JSON some class you are trying to convert a `DataTable` into?  If so, can you please share that class -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sajid Thanks for time and help but I figure out my issue. I mistakenly right the return type of the method to JSON instead of String. When I changed the method return type the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires to have DTO class with required number of properties and then loop over the Dto to bind the datatable fields with DTO properties.

here is the example code

```
    product = new Product
 {
     title = dataTable.Rows[0]["ItemName"].ToString(),
     body_html = dataTable.Rows[0]["BodyHtml"].ToString(),
     vendor = dataTable.Rows[0]["Vendor"].ToString(),
     product_type = dataTable.Rows[0]["ProductType"].ToString(),
     variants = new Variant[1],
     images = new Image[1]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can also return JSON from SQL itself

```
DECLARE @json NVarChar(max)
set @json = (select * from table1 with(nolock)
FOR JSON AUTO);
```